# Magic The Gathering, Blinking the source of a transformation

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When the action that makes a card flip back-face up goes on the stack, I use a card ability like the [Eldrazi Displacer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eldrazi%20Displacer) to blink [Archangel Avacyn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archangel%20Avacyn)

After the "blink" resolves, the card I have on the battlefield now is no longer the source of the ability I have on the stack.

In the ruling it says that

> 112.7a. The source of an activated ability can perform an action even if it no longer exists.

So, the Avacyn source of the triggered ability no longer exists, but it should be flipped bottom-face up.

What will happen? Will a new object be created? Will the activated ability resolve without effect?

Comment: Please name all the cards involved in your situation, that will make answering it a lot easier. You can use the syntax "[mtg:cardname]" to link each card. Be sure to use the exact name if you do.

Comment: I don't completely get your question. Are you talking about blinking Avacyn with her flip-trigger on the stack? If so, she would return face-up and wont flip to 'Avacyn, the Purifier'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you blink Archangel Avacyn while its transform trigger is on the stack, the new Archangel object will not transform.**

You are correct in that the transform trigger will still resolve, even though its source object no longer exists. However, the Archangel that put the transform trigger on the stack was also the object to be flipped. When you blinked the original Archangel, the transform trigger lost track of that object. The transform ability will resolve, but it will not do anything.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.